# Running a shell command from a flask app

Tags: python, shell, flask

I'm trying to run a shell command from a flask app and trying to grab the output. The app I'm trying with is following:

```
from flask import Flask
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")

def hello():
    cmd = ["ls"," -l"]
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    out,err = p.communicate()
    return out
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app.run()
```

The shell command is ok. I checked it outside, but from the browser I'm getting "internal sever error".

*EDIT: As the first answer pointed out it had a typo...But now its running ok but I'm not getting any output in my browser...*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a simple typo. `cd` in the following line should be `cmd`:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cd, # <----
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

**UPDATE**

There's another typo; remove a space in the second item:

```
cmd = ["ls", " -l"]
              ^
```

Comment: edited...but i'm not getting any output in the browser...

Comment: @Aftnix, There's another typo. See the updated answer.

Comment: so all i had was typing errors..i should have debugged it first...

Comment: this answer has a typo.. it shouldn't be `cd` it should be `cmd`

Comment: @nmz787, `cd` came from the question. I mentioned the typo in the very first line.